How do you add a texture to a custom shader's instance properties in Unity? (URP)
I'm writing a 2D game in Unity using the Universal Render Pipeline so that I can take advantage of its automated lighting. I've written a shader that already makes use of some instanced properties, such as custom colours and injury level, and these work nicely.
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
            UNITY_DEFINE_INSTANCED_PROP(half, _Injury)
            UNITY_DEFINE_INSTANCED_PROP(half4, _Custom1)
            UNITY_DEFINE_INSTANCED_PROP(half4, _Custom2)
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

What I'd like to do next is to allow certain of the textures associated with the shader to also be instanced properties, so that I can change them on a case-by-case basis. These are ancillary textures used to add custom patterning to various items of clothing without having to make a load of alternative textures.
The problem is, I can't find any reference as to how to declare a texture as an instanced property. I'm pretty certain this ought to be possible since the MaterialPropertiesBlock class has a SetTexture function in a similar format to the ones used for setting float values, but I can't find any examples that show you how.
Can anyone show me the process? Even just the proper declaration of the instanced property would help, as I've tried several different ways and they all give very cryptic errors.

And again, having struggled for about an hour, I find the answer within minutes of posting a question here. This is getting to be a habit. Oh well. Apparently the correct form eluded me because the correct class name isn't 2D, as it appears in the shader properties section, or Texture, as it appears in the c# code, or TEXTURE2D as it appears in the macros that define them as variables, but Texture2D.
Only the texture itself needs to be in the instanced properties section. The sampler should be created in the usual way.
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
            UNITY_DEFINE_INSTANCED_PROP(Texture2D, _PatternMask)
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

        SAMPLER(sampler_PatternMask);

